# How to include a downloaded go package in your go file

Tags: go

I have downloaded the package regexp2 using this command

> go get github.com/dlclark/regexp2/...

Then I am using this code to import the package

```
package main

import "regexp2"

func main() {
  //do stuff with regexp2
}
```

But when i use this it throws this error:

> cannot find package "regexp2" in any of:
>          c:\go\src\regexp2 (from $GOROOT)
>          C:\Users\me\go\src\regexp2 (from $GOPATH)

Comment: use `import "github.com/dlclark/regexp2"`

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportingRemote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the entire repository :
`import "github.com/dlclark/regexp2"`

It's basically the path, from your GOPATH, to this package